# No PulseAudio in Skype Sound Devices choices, and microphone does not work…

Tags: sound, skype, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a new re-install of Mythbuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

When I installed Skype 4.1.0.20 and tried to use it, I found that under options/Sound Devices/, under the three (Microphone,Speakers and Ringing) there were no "PulseAudio server(local)" options. This was unexpected since on my several other Linux systems that also use PulseAudio "PulseAudio server(local)" was the only option.

Also the microphone is now mute, although not shown muted in alsamixer.

In place of "PulseAudio server(local)" there is a long list of devices including many for the Logitech AK5370 microphone I use.  None seem to work.

Furthermore the button to open PulseAudio Volume Control on Options/Sound Devices missing in the new install.

What could possibly be wrong?

Update: Strange behavior:  I discovered one of the eight choices will work.  But it seems that after cold boot, it is a different one.  So everyday after boot, I spend a ¼ hour or trying each one until I find one that works.  ..?..?..?

Comment: Have you tried updating Skype to 4.3? Are you still seeing these issues?